# $\mathbb{Z}_6/\mathbb{Z}_2$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Recently in class my teacher mentioned that the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_6/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

May I ask why is this so?

Also, what do elements in $\mathbb{Z}_6/\mathbb{Z}_2$ look like? I thought they were of the form $a+\mathbb{Z}_2$, but then there would be 6 elements ($1\leq a\leq 6$), which is not quite right.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Regard $\mathbb Z_2 = \{0,3\}$ as the $2$-element additive subgroup of $\mathbb Z_6 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: In general $g+H$ may be equal to $g'+H$ in the quotient group $G/H$, even if $g$ and $g'$ are different. In fact, that will be the case if and only if the difference $g-g'$ belongs to the subgroup $H$ (by definition of quotient group). In particular, $g+H=(g+h)+H$ for all the elements $h$ of $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ contains the elements $0$ and $3$ (since $3+3 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$).  So consider $\mathbb{Z}_{2} = \{0,3\} \subset \mathbb{Z}_{6}$, then $1+\mathbb{Z}_{2} = \{1,4\} = 4 + \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. This should let you complete the exercise (you are correct about how to represent the elements of the factor group).

Answer (score 4):

How is $\mathbb Z_2:=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_6:=\mathbb Z/6 \mathbb Z$ in the first place?
Well, it isn't in a very natural way (at least if $2,6$ were replaced by bigger numbers, we might run into choices). To obtain an injective homomorphism $\mathbb Z_2\to\mathbb Z/6$, we need a homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ that has $2\mathbb Z$ in its kernel. I suggest $x\mapsto 3x+6\mathbb Z$, so that the desired injection $\mathbb Z_2\to\mathbb Z_6$ is $x+2\mathbb Z\mapsto 3x+6\mathbb Z$.
With this homomorhism understood as inclsion you may show that $\mathbb Z_6/\mathbb Z_2\cong \mathbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 3):

$|\mathbb{Z}_6/\mathbb{Z}_2| = 6/2 = 3$ and there is only a group of order 3, namely...

Comment: Good one is an straightforward one +1

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_{pq}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p}\times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$ if and only if $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.  Let $p=2$ and $q=3$....  Then convince yourself that
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times \mathbb{Z}_{q}}{\mathbb{Z}_{p}}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{q}$$

EDIT:  For the first part, go to:[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171115074239/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/73205.html)
For the centered equation: In general, if you have $G\times H$ then any element from here is of the form $(g,h)$ for $g\in G$ and $h\in H$.  When you "mod-out" by $G$ then you are saying any elements from here are the same.  So for example $(g_1,h)=(g_2,h)$ for any $h\in H$ and any $g_i\in G$.  But then distict elements of this space are distinct if and only if the second coordinate is different (that is, $(a,b)\neq (c,d)$ if and only if $b\neq d$.... but this is precisely $H$).

Comment: Of course you're not wrong, but I really don't think repeating the statement the OP doesn't understand will help them understand it.

Comment: Does this work only for p,q relatively prime? I tried Z4/Z2=Z2 it seems to work as well.

Comment: This is missing the point by confusing it with a sort of converse.  While it is true that $\mathbb{Z}_4 / \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ it is NOT true that $\mathbb{Z}_4\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  For example, the first is cyclic but the latter is not. In my answer, however, it is the case that $\mathbb{Z}_6\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3$ and so from here we get to "cancel" (precisely mod) out the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ term and we're left with $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Put another way...$ \mathbb{Z}_4 /\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2}{\mathbb{Z}_2}$  HOWEVER this doesn't prove that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Answer (score 0):

consider the surjective homomorphism from Z6 to Z3 - f(i(mod6))=i(mod3)
(you must show this function is well defined)
and use the fundamental homorphism thm.